# FormValidation: display placeholder property in message

Tags: jquery

Need your help guys.

I am using FormValidation in validating my inputs in a form.
 I also created a js file where FormValidation is being called.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $().DMSFormValidator('#frmAccessDetails');
});

(function () {
 $.fn.DMSFormValidator = function (FormNameID, ErrorContainerID) {
  var $form = $(FormNameID);
    
  $form.formValidation({
   framework: 'bootstrap',
   err: {
    container: (ErrorContainerID == null || ErrorContainerID.length == 0) ? null : ErrorContainerID
   },
   icon: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
   },
   fields: {
    txtNetworkID: {
     message: 'The network ID is not valid',
     validators: {
      notEmpty: {
       message: 'The network ID is required'
      },
      stringLength: {
       min: 7,
       max: 30,
       message: 'The network ID must be more than 7 and less than 30 characters long'
      }, 
      regexp: {
       regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
       message: 'The network ID can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
      }
     }
    },
    txtEmail: {
     validators: {
      notEmpty: {
       message: 'The email address is required'
      },
      emailAddress: {
       message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
      }
     }
    },
    txtPassword: {
     validators: {
      notEmpty: {
       message: 'The password is required'
      }
     }
    },    
    TextRequiredField: {
     selector: '.TextRequiredField',
     validators: {
      notEmpty: {
       message: ($('.TextRequiredField').prop('placeholder')) + ' field is required'
      },
      regexp: {
       regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\. ]+$/,
       message: 'The accepts only consist of alphabetical, number, dot, underscore and space'
      }
     }
    }
   }
  });
  return $form;
 }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/bundles/40aab700698a291c5ce712a44ec8bc34.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-3">
 <form id="frmAccessDetails">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">Add New Access</div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Access Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control TextRequiredField" id="txtAccessName" name="txtxAccessGroupName" placeholder="Access Group Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Description</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control TextRequiredField" id="txtDescription" name="txtDescription" placeholder="Description" />
      </div>
     
 

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-inline pull-right">
       <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
         <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
         <button type="button" onclick="javascript: window.location='@Url.Action("Index", "Access")'" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></i> Cancel</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Take a look at the snippet. I am using single validation for all text field. However, i want to use the placeholder to display. How can I access the control and it's placeholder? Seems like it is an array and it's getting the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#contact-form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        message: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

});

[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/)

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks for your comment. However, I'm using FormValidations.